# Uninstall Nextcloud on 16.04

Tags: nextcloud

How can I uninstall NextCloud completely from this installation?

I have no idea why this server cam with NextCloud installed but I need it gone

Comment: How to uninstall always depends on how it was installed. If it was like mentioned here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04 - it should be as easy as `sudo snap remove nextcloud`. This you could've easily googled.

Answer (score 8):

If installed with `sudo snap install nextcloud`, then:

```
sudo snap remove nextcloud
```