# Is nextcloud preinstalled on Ubuntu server? or my mistake?

Tags: server, software-installation, uninstall, nextcloud

TLDR:
I found the ip of my home ubuntu server Nas (base install), listed on the home network connections web page of my router (while browsing from home), a Fritzbox7530, from Zen broadband (a well rated uk provider).  It was a clickable link, so I clicked it, was not sure what I would get, another page listing open ports? graph of packets sent and received?

I got this:

[image]

Riiiight.

Well this raises a few questions.  I cannot recall doing `apt install nextcloud` at any point.  Might I have accidentally clicked 'install nextcloud' in the ubuntu server install settings when I set it up a few months ago?

So this install page has sat there waiting for anyone who went to that ip to `install` and set an `admin user`?

Is this the normal way you set up next cloud? I thought it would all be from the command line ssh in using a privileged user?

(yes the odd ip is the router's choice not mine)

My query here may reveal my ignorance, but is this set up method a little bit risky? create admin and install from any local IP over web, not cli and ssh?

Second question: nextcloud is not part of ubuntu server is it? So I miskeyed/clicked on install? So I have luckily not had anyone discover this (wife and children only) and setup next cloud, locking me out? (I wouldn't have any issue negotiating hand back from family but....)

I do not think I want to set up next cloud, so how do I change this? ssh in and uninstall nextcloud `apt remove nextcloud` and close http and https ports? [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422097/whats-the-right-way-to-uninstall-nextcloud-fron-linux-when-it-was-installed-via) looks helpful.

Comment: "*...is this set up method a little bit risky?*" Only if you are in the habit of letting strangers or hackers or crooks wander your local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be installed if you select it - which you apparently did.

For Ubuntu Server 22.04, this screen will come up during install:

[image]

So it seems you have selected `nextcloud` here. And yes, this will create the web service, allowing the admin (who performed the install) to create an admin user right away.

This is perfectly normal, and it's basically your mistake that you installed it, but never went the full way and created the admin user also.